# Sencha Architect set SDK path locally - Beginner

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am using `Sencha Architect` for development. I need to point the following 2 files to the `Sencha Touch 2.2` SDK that i downloaded. Each time i save and build the application via `Sencha Architect` it gets overridden. How can i over this ?

```
<script src="http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.2.1/sencha-touch-all.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.2.1/resources/css/sencha-touch.css">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Sencha Architect, Go to **Project Inspector** --> Under **Resources** --> Select **Library** --> Now, in the **Config** Panel --> Remove the default url (http://cdn.sencha.com/touch/sencha-touch-2.2.1/) under **Library Base Path** --> Specify the location of your Sencha Touch folder (Touch 2.2.1 or some version) you've downloaded and saved on your computer. That should do.

Best Luck!